# Python - executing two functions in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and I have following problem.
I'm trying to divide a variable (counta) by 3 and get the result every 10 seconds. At the same time I want to add 1 to the counter every time I press 'a'. The problem is that I'm using a method where I can only add 1 every 10 seconds. Please can you advise what could be changed so that I could add 1 whenever I like and i still get the current result (counta/3). Thank you in advance for your help. This is my code so far:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import sched, time 




counta = 0
Timer = 0




def on_press(key):


    if key.char == 'a':
        #print("")
        global counta
        counta += 1
        #print("Aktuell" + str(counta))

    elif key.char == 'p':
        print(int(counta/3))

    elif key.char == 's':
        Stand(counta, Timer)


    else:
        print("Falsche Taste!")
        print("a = counta")


def Stand(counta, Timer):
    while Timer < 10: 
        print(str(counta/3))
        time.sleep(1)
        Timer += 1




with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You need to read up on the Threading package. It allows you to execute a function in a thread in parallel with other functions.

Comment: you have to use `Listener` in differen way. Create `listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)` before `while` loop, and use `listener.join()` after `while` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Listener` in different way

```
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

while Timer < 10: 
    print(str(counta/3))
    time.sleep(1)
    Timer += 1

#listener.stop()
listener.join()
```

or using your function

```
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

Stand(counta, Timer)

#listener.stop()
listener.join()
```

---

BTW: class `Listener` already uses `thread` to listen keys - `class Listener(threading.Thread):`.

---

**EDIT:** I released that you can also use it this way

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:

    while Timer < 10: 
        print(str(counta/3))
        time.sleep(1)
        Timer += 1

    #listener.stop()
    listener.join()
```

or using your function

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:

    Stand(counta, Timer)

    #listener.stop()
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I added example which uses `with Listener()`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a Tread :

```
import treading # at begin of your file


thread = threading.Thread(target=Stand) # create thread with your function
thread.start() # launch your function
```

Note that print method can reduce time execution of your function, and print in thread won't be recommended.